# Issue with data capture script

Tags: perl, cgi

I cant seem to get this script to work using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize).

I know it's probably something simple, but I just can't see it.

I think it's failing at [`HTML::TokeParser`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TokeParser) for some reason.

I get this error message

```
Can't call method "get_token" on an undefined value at Untitled line 13
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = "http://slashdot.org/";

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$agent->get($url);

my $stream = HTML::TokeParser->new( $agent->{content} );

while ( my $token = $stream->get_token ) {
    my $ttype = shift @{$token};

    if ( $ttype eq "S" ) {
        my ( $tag, $attr, $attrseq, $rawtxt ) = @{$token};

        if ( $tag eq "div" ) {
            if ( $rawtxt =~ /id="text-/m ) {
                print $stream->get_trimmed_text( $tag, "/div" );
                print "\n\n\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what issue you're seeing? It's not clear what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Script fails It should return HTML data between "<div> ... </div>" from http://slashdot.org

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Does the script print anything? If so, what does it print?

Comment: I get this error msg: Can't call method "get_token" on an undefined value at Untitled line 13.

Comment: `use strict` and `use warnings` if you want debugging help.

Comment: You must have read it a hundred times by now? Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. This applies especially if you are asking for help with debugging as, if you omit them, you haven't even taken the most basic steps to find the fault yourself.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is to write a simple web server app that copies the contents of `slashdot.org` to its output? Is that right? The only reason I can imagine to do something like that is to limit access to specific parts of `slashdot.org` , but your code doesn't hint at that. Most of all, it's almost certainly contrary to the slashdot terms of service for its pages to be read from another web server. Please explain your goal.

Comment: The recommended way to retrieve the contents of a WWW::Mech response is using `$mech->content( args )`, not `$mech->{content}`.

Comment: Also note that slashdot has an [rss feed](http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot) that you could use. I think that might be easier to parse than the HTML page, but pick your poison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [HTML::TokeParser](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TokeParser#p-HTML::TokeParser-new-document-opt):

> `$p = HTML::TokeParser->new( \$document, %opt );`
>
> `The object constructor argument is either a file name, a file handle object, or the complete document to be parsed. Extra options can be provided as key/value pairs and are processed as documented by the base classes.`
>
> `If the argument is a plain scalar, then it is taken as the name of a file to be opened and parsed. If the file can't be opened for reading, then the constructor will return undef and $! will tell you why it failed.`

From your script:

> `Can't call method "get_token" on an undefined value at Untitled line 13`

Check the arguments that you're passing to initialise the HTML::TokeParser object:

```
my $stream = HTML::TokeParser->new($agent->{content});
```

First off, you should be using [WWW::Mechanize's `content`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#CONTENT-HANDLING-METHODS) method to get the page contents, and secondly, you need to pass in a reference to the content, not the content itself. To correct your code, you need

```
my $stream = HTML::TokeParser->new( \$agent->content );
```

You might also want to add an error check to ensure that you are successfully retrieving the slashdot page before starting the parser (e.g. using `$agent->success`).